C++17 Are non-static POD class members initialized with curly braces {} set to 0?
Got code review comment that my non-static class POD members be set to an invalid value. I agree that the initial value should be invalid. For my cases, 0 is invalid. Here's an example:
class A
{
  int a_{};  // Is a_ initialized to 0?
  double b_{}; // Is b_ initialized to 0.0?
  // etc.
};

I added the {} sometimes to handle compiler warnings that these class members should be initialized. I thought they would be initialized to zero. (Empirical observation indicates they are 0, but I am looking for authoritative sources one way or the other.)
I looked at these two links but could not say for certain that {} results in 0.
Meaning of default initialization changed in C++11?
Default and value initialization of POD types in C++
A clear simple source would be useful. I tried finding something here without luck.
https://eel.is/c++draft/

What exactly are you looking for? {} here is simply a default member initializer like = 0 would be and the initialization simply follows the normal initialization rules just as in a variable definition int a_{}; anywhere else. There is nothing special about the class properties, the storage duration or that it appears in a class at all.

"Got code review comment that my non-static class POD members be set to an invalid value.": That's really weird approach btw. The constructor of the class ought to initialize all members into valid states that preserve the class invariant. That's why proper classes, rather than just aggregate structs, are used. There should never be any invalid observable state. Initializing to an invalid state just prevents tools from recognizing the mistake of not correctly initializing to a valid state.


{} here is simply a default member initializer. I would like to know what value a_ and b_ are set to with this {} initializer? I thought the values would be 0 and 0.0 respectively. But the reviewer doesn't think that is the case. (I can change the {} to, say, {-999} and that would satisfy, but we've been using {} for POD types throughout the project. If not zero, then we may need to change all or some of our {}'s.


@user17732522 I don't think anyone was recommending that they be set to invalid values, they were saying that this is what this syntax does, which is why they complained about it.

@Barmar "I agree that the initial value should be invalid. For my cases, 0 is invalid."? Doesn't sound like it to me.

@user17732522 But he also wrote "I thought they would be initialized to zero"

@user17732522 - weird approach btw.
The lead prefers the "fail fast". The lead wants "invalid values". Since 0 is invalid, I want to know if I am complying with his recommendation.

"But the reviewer doesn't think that is the case.": Then they are wrong. But your example is incomplete. Whether or not the default initializer is even used will depend on how the constructor looks, i.e. whether or not it explicitly initializes the member with some other initializer. If it doesn't and the default member initializer is used, then the behavior is, as I said, exactly the same as in any normal declaration. That's just why I was confused by your very specific conditions of the question. I will write an answer anyway. Give me a sec.

@PaulH But you don't fail fast? Fail fast would be to set the compiler to error if any initializer is missing.

I second user17732522. Something might be lost in how you convey the review, but your lead's comments don't inspire confidence in their position.

@user17732522, good point about the ctor. Here it is: A:A(std::string) : filename_(filename) {}

Assuming filename_ is not a std::string&, make that filename_(std::move(filename))

@user17732522 "Fail fast would be to set the compiler to error" I would call that fail fastest. (In fact the compiler gives warnings about uninitialized member variables.) The lead wrote: "The goal is fail fast.  If those are left uninitialized, you could get any value there, which may be valid." (Then we would hope to catch the problem in our gtests.)

@TedLyngmo "filename_(std::move(filename))" Good point in general. Since the ctor is run once upon startup of this forever running process, not sure this optimization is worth changing to be reviewed again. They already beamed me for being concerned about optimization issues, since this is a prototype and the integration team will tell us if and where we need to improve performance.

@PaulH Sounds like you might not need a string at all. Is it initialized with a string literal? If so, a std::string_view might do.

To answer your question: I don't have the strength to dig in the standard right now, but, yes, they are initialized to 0 and 0.0. Edit: Oh, and there came an answer pointing out the relevant sections :-)

@TedLyngmo, "string literal?". The process starts off by creating multiple threads that run forever. Each thread has its own unique filename. Cannot hard-code because later we'll have a config file that indicates the filename and its location for the next startup (so I lied - it only runs forever until someone wants to change the filename(s)).

@PaulH A string literal would be "foo.txt" for example. Ok, if it's not hardcoded, go with std::string. I wouldn't call using std::move in this case overambitious though. There's no need to waste CPU cycles on something that can be so easily dealt with.

If the reviewers are uncertain, nothing stops you from being explicit with int a_ {0};

@BoP Or just completely non-fancy int a_ = 0; and double b_ = 0.0;. But as I mentioned at the end of my answer, {} or maybe cleaner = {} is actually really nice, because it is practically always "correct" and doesn't require me to check the type to understand the intended semantics.

Time to go back and (re)educate your code reviewer.  This isn't an esoteric corner of C++, it's pretty bread-and-butter.

@Eljay - I take it you do not like initializing a_ and b_ to invalid values. The implementation requires that they be set dynamically before used. Using bad values identifies the scenario during lifetime maintenance that they are getting dynamically set, or else, unit test fails sooner rather than later.

I take it you do not like initializing a_ and b_ to invalid values.  No, it's rather that I do not like uninitialized variables.

I'd challenge the suggestion of setting any class member to an invalid value. Better that all members are initialised to a value that makes sense (e.g. consistent with class invariants), and avoid creating an instance of a class until enough information (e.g. data read from a file) is available to initialise it correctly. Initialising members to invalid values (or having a "uninitialised" or "partly initialised" state of the object) is a ripe opportunity to forget to check and use invalid values or to use an uninitialised object as if it is correctly initialised - which rarely goes well.

If we set our class members to an invalid parameter, and if they are not set correctly, we ensure that our gtests will fail. This protects us from future maintenance mistakes.

(I noticed the tags too late. My references are to the final draft for C++23. For C++17 the rules are effectively the same and they have been the same since default member initializers have been introduced in C++11, but there will have been some stuff moved around in the standard texts relative to the references below.)

Assuming the default member initializer {} is actually used, i.e. the used constructor doesn't specify any other initializer for the given member, or, if this is an aggregate class, aggregate initialization doesn't specify any other initializer for the member, then the initialization of these members will be exactly the same as if their declarations appeared in some other context, e.g. as block scope variables. (See especially [class.base.init]/9.1.)
So consider the {} initializer for types int/double. Initialization behavior is specified in long chains of decision rules starting in [dcl.init.general]/16. The first rule that applies is (16.1), because {} is a braced-init-list and all initialization with braces leads to list-initialization according to [dcl.init.list]/3.
The first item to apply in this new decision chain is (3.11), which states that the object is value-initialized (because the initializer list is empty and the type isn't a class type or reference type or any other of the special cases before it in the chain).
Value-initialization is defined in [dcl.init.general]/9 and in this decision chain the last item (9.3) is the first to apply, because neither int nor double are class or array types, and it states that the object is zero-initialized.
Zero-initialization is defined in [dcl.init.general]/6 via another decision chain and there (6.1) already applies, because int and double are scalar types. It states that the object is initialized as if by converting an integer literal 0 to its type.
At this point I hope it is clear that the int member's value will be 0 and double member's value will be 0.0 without going through the implicit conversion rules in [conv] as well.

More generally: {} or, almost equivalently, = {} should in practice always be correct to initialize any object to its canonical "empty" state.
For scalar types it is 0 converted to its type as shown above, for aggregate types it is the equivalent applied to each aggregate element recursively, for non-aggregate class types it is either a call to the default constructor if it is user-provided or full (recursive) zero-initialization followed by default initialization if the default constructor exists, but is not user-provided, or potentially a call to a std::initializer_list constructor with empty initializer list.
So, except for class types with a constructor that is intentionally written to leave the object in an invalid or non-empty state, the result will be a fully initialized object to an "empty" state and if an object has a notion of an empty state that is independent of any inputs, then it should also be possible to initialize it with {}, assuming no evil class design.
The only thing {} might not guarantee is zero-initialization of padding (i.e. as memset would permit for trivially-copyable types). Some forms of initialization do also guarantee that, but it isn't clear what that is even worth, because the standard doesn't specify that padding has stable values at all anyway (in contrast to C).

Thanks for all the references. I see that zero-initialization is setting bits to 0. So, I guess a double filled with all 0's is interpreted as 0.0. At last minute I found this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization and in it this line: " int n0{};  // value-initialization (to zero)". I'll include your links in my explanation to the lead and this last one to my lead. Will let you know his response.

@PaulH No, it doesn't set all bits to zero. It converts the literal 0 to a value of the target type. The value of the target type for int is 0 and for double is 0.0. What kind of value representation these values have in memory doesn't matter at all. For example 0.0 could be represented by all bits set to 1. Of course, in practice, maybe with the exception of some old exotic architectures with trap representations, a value 0 integer is represented by all bits of the object being zero and in common floating point formats 0.0 happens to also be represented by all bits zero.

Ok, thanks for the double clarification. I just don't understand why I couldn't get your information in this: https://eel.is/c++draft/

@PaulH Just go to the same sections as I referenced in my answer. The numbering might be a bit different, because that is the latest standard draft for the upcoming C++26.

@PaulH A bit tricky is only that [dcl.init] is hidden under [dcl.dcl] because of a restructuring that happened at one point. So you want https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.

@PaulH But cppreference is of course easier to digest as a reference than the standard (drafts) are. I would recommend referencing that unless someone is vehemently disagreeing with what it says.

Just saw your note about C++23. We were at C++11, but recently I changed it to C++17. We like really mature products. Do you know of a general starting point for either C++11 or 17 that I can find similar links?

@PaulH The official standard documents must be bought from ISO or a national body, but drafts which are effectively the same up to editorial changes are linked here. Also beware that defect reports which should apply retroactively won't be incorporated into these drafts (nor in the official standard anyway).

I will choose the C++17 pdf since I figure all the errata in C++11 that applies to this question would probably be fixed by C++17. The pdf is great for the global search. Thanks again, user17732522
